# R does not finish execution

Tags: r, function

[image]

Hello during a script execution of a function R does not end execution and rot return any result.. but when i execute the script out of the function itself it does give the result.. could you please help me going around this? Thanks

```
findWords <- function(metasInteresse)
 {
     stopWords <- c("da","de","do","a","no","que","com","","e","se","as","o","na","os","name","para","em","og")
     
     vTest<- strsplit(metasInteresse,',')
     
     a<-1
     j<-1
     st<-1
     
     while(a<= length(vTest))
     {
         while(st<= length(stopWords))
         {
             if(vTest[[a]][j] == stopWords[st])
             {
                 vTest[[a]][j] <- vTest[[a1]][j]
                 a<- a1
                 j<- j2
                 st<- st1          
             }  
             else
             {
                 a<- a1
                 j<- j1
                 st<- st1
             }
         }  
     }
     return(DATAFRAME(metasInteresse))
 }
```

Comment: What does the script look like and can you isolate which line of the script is causing this?

Comment: findWords <- function(metasInteresse)
{ stopWords < c("da","de","do","a","no","que","com","","g")   vTest<- strsplit(metasInteresse,',') a<-1  j<-1  st<-1 while(a<= length(vTest))
{ while(st<= length(stopWords))
{ if(vTest[[a]][j] == stopWords[st])
+             { vTest[[a]][j] <- vTest[[a+1]][j] a<- a+1 j<- j+2 st<- st+1 } 
+             else
+             {
+                 a<- a+1
+                 j<- j+1
+                 st<- st+1
+             }
+         } 
+     }
+     
+     
+     
+     
+     
+     return(DATAFRAME(metaVetor))
+     
+ }

Comment: Add it to the original post properly formatted.

Comment: Very likely a result of having two nested while loops, waiting for an event to occur which never does. If you could provide an example of your problem, with an initial data set and a desired output, it would be possible to find alternative methods.

Comment: Yes looks like, the code i was executing is the above, not from the question, misteriously it was not increasing the variables that control the loop, i dont know the reason..i found a work around for it..